# Wildcards in feature selection using geopandas?

Tags: python, geopandas

I need to select the rows that are according to the following line:

Like this is for numbers:

```
data[data['field']<4]
```

I need this: where the words `do` are inside the name of a given row

```
data[data['field'] LIKE '%do%']
```

and this: where it starts with 01

```
data[data['field'] LIKE '01%']
```

I think it needs `regex` but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple patterns or more advanced `regex` patterns in the [`str.contains()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) method:

```
data[data['field'].str.contains('do')]
```

For the case where the strings needs to start with a pattern, you can either use a regex pattern in `contains` (`^` denotes the pattern should be at the beginning) or `match` which defaults to looking for patterns starting from the beginning:

```
data[data['field'].str.contains('^01')]
data[data['field'].str.match('01')]
```

Comment: Can you tell me also how to do the opposite, to leave out those that start with 01?

Comment: You can "invert" a mask selection using`~`: `data[~data['field'].contains(..)]`